# How to integrate noVNC in Angular 16 / How to launch noVNC terminal from Angular 16

Tags: angular, websocket, angular16, novnc, websockify

I have been trying to integrate noVNC in my angular application where I am unable to import the required module to launch noVNC. I have been facing the following issue.

```
import * as RFB from "../../../node_modules/novnc/core/rfb.js";
import RFB from '@novnc/novnc/core/rfb';
import { RFB } from 'novnc';
public rfb: RFB;
```

> ```
> tried with all 3 imports but getting error as
> ```

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../app/ui.js' in 'C:\Chethan\Projects\VM-ware\nexus_gui\node_modules\novnc\lib\input'
```

I have imported as shown above but unable to proceed further
[GithubLink](https://github1s.com/nasrob/vnc-client/blob/HEAD/src/app/app.component.ts)

I am following above github project but its for a older version of angular